# Accessing ubuntu virtual machine host from windows browser

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, virtualbox, ubuntu-14.04

I have a virtualbox ubuntu machine running a hellow world flask app.

I tried having the app display on 127.0.0.1:5000 and 0.0.0.0:5000

But both when I try to load up on my windows browser don't resolve.

When I run ifconfig in ubuntu virtual machine I get this:

```
ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:6f:2c:93  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe6f:2c93/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:657 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:559 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:61322 (61.3 KB)  TX bytes:73104 (73.1 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

And when on my windows machine I run ip config I get this:

```
ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 4:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::2140:c809:4677:98bc%3
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.32.16.32
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.0.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.128.128.128

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::3568:3fc7:1697:a475%10
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.{2543650F-5CEA-40B8-B085-A54A628D3DCE}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.{8A555006-09A6-4A20-986D-F59F5741DCCE}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

But for some reason when I go to 192.168.56.1 in my windows browswer  it loads a white page.  If I go to 192.168.56.1:5000 it says it can not connect.

In my virtual box I have it "attached to: NAT"
and port forwarding rules show

ssh TCP 127.0.0.1 host port 2222 guest ip is empty and guest port is 22

My flask app shows

```
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
```

Also tried with

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
```

Comment: You probably need to portforward port 5000 as well.

Comment: @GregHNZ Is there a default port I could change it too instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer to your question you can find in VirtualBox documentation:
https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html
*6.3.1. Configuring port forwarding with NAT*

You can just forward port 5000 from guest OS (Ubuntu) to host one. On the host side you can use the same port number (if it's not occupied by someone else, sure)

Comment: I've read it a few times and I am still confused.  So I go into port forwarding rules and set it up a new rule w/ a port and the ip?

Comment: Your answer helped me get there.  Thank you.  Will give you credit.  What I needed to do was go into port forwarding rules of the vm in virtualbox and click port forwarding rules  set up the host port as say 1234 and the guest port as 5000.